# How to run inference from the SavedModel locally?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run a model locally. I'm trying to train and predict models from web course:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/blob/master/tensorflow-planespotting/trainer_yolo/main.py

A model was trained with above code. This is a YOLO object detection model that detect airplane built with `tf.estimator`. Training was done successfully with provided codes but I don't know about how to inference the model.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# DATA
DATA = './samples/airplane_sample.png'

# Model: This directory contains saved_model.pb and variables
SAVED_MODEL_DIR = './1559196417/'

def decode_image():
    img_bytes = tf.read_file(DATA)
    decoded = tf.image.decode_image(img_bytes, channels=3)
    return tf.cast(decoded, dtype=tf.uint8)

def main1():
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], SAVED_MODEL_DIR)
        img = decode_image()
        result = sess.run(['classes'], feed_dict={'input': img})
        print(result)

def main2():
    model = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_DIR)
    pred = model({'image_bytes': [decode_image()], 'square_size': [tf.placeholder(tf.int32)]})
    print(pred)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2()
```

Above is a code written by me but it doesn't work. Even I don't know what is a problem. Incorrect input type? Improper API? Could you give me some advice to me?

Answer (score 1):

First run `saved_model_cli show --all --dir SAVED_MODEL_DIR` in the terminal outside of python to inspect the saved model and check that it has the right tags, inputs and outputs. From there it takes a bit of wrangling to get the necessary info out of the API.

```py
def extract_tensors(signature_def, graph):
    output = dict()

    for key in signature_def:
        value = signature_def[key]

        if isinstance(value, tf.TensorInfo):
            output[key] = graph.get_tensor_by_name(value.name)

    return output

def extract_tags(signature_def, graph):
    output = dict()

    for key in signature_def:
        output[key] = dict()
        output[key]['inputs'] = extract_tensors(
            signature_def[key].inputs, graph)
        output[key]['outputs'] = extract_tensors(
            signature_def[key].outputs, graph)

    return output

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as session:
    serve = tf.saved_model.load(
        session, tags=['serve'], export_dir=SAVED_MODEL_DIR)

    tags = extract_tags(serve.signature_def, session.graph)
    model = tags['serving_default']
```

From there you can try `print(model['inputs'], model['outputs'])` to see which inputs and outputs were exported and if they agree with `saved_model_cli`, if you need another tag then just replace `serving_default` with that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile('./1559196417/saved_model.pb', 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        image = cv2.imread('./samples/airplane_sample.png')

        rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        rgb_img_expanded = np.expand_dims(rgb_img, axis=0)

        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('classes:0')
        result = sess.run([classes],feed_dict={image_tensor: rgb_img_expanded})
```

Comment: `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.` from `od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)`. This code doesn't work. (it seems a graph couldn't be built.)

Comment: You have to freeze your inference graph and use that not the saved_model.pb.
I am also not sure if the Tensor names are correct. You have to pass the correct name into get_tensor_by_name('...').

Comment: You can check the names of the Tenors with this Code.

    import tensorflow as tf
    gf = tf.GraphDef()
    m_file = open("frozen_graph.pb",'rb')
    gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())
  
    with open('somefile1.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        for n in gf.node:
            the_file.write(n.name+'\n')

    file = open('somefile1.txt','r')
    data = file.readlines()
    print( "output name = " )
    print(data[len(data)-1])
    print ("Input name = ")
    file.seek ( 0 )
    print (file.readline())